# Jetty embedded server - change the path where the war file will be deployed

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I am using Jetty 9.2 to run a war file inside the embedded Jetty server. I have no 'web.xml', no webapp folder, just the war file i want to deploy. I am running the war file without any problems with this code:

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;

public class DeployWar {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Server server = new Server(9090);
    WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
    webapp.setContextPath("/");

    webapp.setWar("test.war");
    server.setHandler(webapp);

    try {
        server.start();
        System.out.println("Press any key to stop the server...");
        System.in.read(); System.in.read();
        server.stop();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("error");
    }

    System.out.println("Server stopped");
}
}
```

The 'problem' is that the war is deployed(unpacked) in a predefined location (something like C:\Users\MyPCname\AppData\Local\Temp\jetty...) and i want to change it to something different, let's say to the bin folder of my project.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the answer to my problem turned out to be pretty simple. The desired functionality is already provided by jetty. I had to just add these lines above the 'setWar' method:

```
File webappsFolder = new File("jettyWebapps/");
webappsFolder.mkdirs();
webapp.setTempDirectory(webappsFolder);
```

[here](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/9.2.11.v20150529/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/WebAppContext.html#setTempDirectory(java.io.File)) you can see the jetty documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty well described in jetty documentation. Please have a look at http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/embedding-jetty.html.

```
public class OneWebApp
   {
     public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
      {
    // Create a basic jetty server object that will listen on port 8080.
    // Note that if you set this to port 0 then a randomly available port
    // will be assigned that you can either look in the logs for the port,
    // or programmatically obtain it for use in test cases.
    Server server = new Server(8080);

    // Setup JMX
    MBeanContainer mbContainer = new MBeanContainer(
            ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer());
    server.addBean(mbContainer);

    // The WebAppContext is the entity that controls the environment in
    // which a web application lives and breathes. In this example the
    // context path is being set to "/" so it is suitable for serving root
    // context requests and then we see it setting the location of the war.
    // A whole host of other configurations are available, ranging from
    // configuring to support annotation scanning in the webapp (through
    // PlusConfiguration) to choosing where the webapp will unpack itself.
    WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
    webapp.setContextPath("/");
    File warFile = new File(
            "C:\Users\MyPCname\AppData\Local\Temp\jetty\your.war");
    webapp.setWar(warFile.getAbsolutePath());
    webapp.addAliasCheck(new AllowSymLinkAliasChecker());

    // A WebAppContext is a ContextHandler as well so it needs to be set to
    // the server so it is aware of where to send the appropriate requests.
    server.setHandler(webapp);

    // Start things up! 
    server.start();

    // The use of server.join() the will make the current thread join and
    // wait until the server is done executing.
    // See            http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()
    server.join();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Eduard and sorry for the delayed reply. Unfortunately, i have tried the code above but i did not see any difference. Additionally, i have noticed that we are defining the path where we will look for the war file but we are not setting the path where the war file will be deployed (unpacked), which is what i am looking for.

Comment: The comments of the code above are declaring this: "configurations are available, ranging from configuring to support annotation scanning in the webapp to **choosing where the webapp will unpack itself**". So this is the functionality i want to achieve...